# Who is being modified in this sentence "Brand rode among them, nervous with excitement."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Brand rode among them, nervous with excitement.

What does this phrase *nervous with excitement* describe, *Brand* or *them*?

Comment: In a poetic, elliptical style it could mean either. In general use, only Brand.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's ambiguous. In practice, it's almost always Brand being modified here. This sort of adjective clause almost always sounds odd modifying a pronoun. No matter what pronoun I choose to replace *them* in this sentence, the parser in my brain reaches the same conclusion: You must have really meant Brand was the nervous one, even though the clause comes after the pronoun, because otherwise you wouldn't have structured it so strangely.

Thus:

- Always structure your adjectives and adjectival clauses so as to make it clear what's modified.

> Nervous with excitement, Brand rode among them.

- Avoid using adjective clauses to modify pronouns.